# Counting Question Using Fundamental Counting Principle

Tags: combinatorics

The registrar at a certain university classifies each student by major (32 majors), sex (m,f), year(f,s,j,s) and by minor (32 minors). Each student can opt for one minor or no minor. How many different combinations possible.

I do the following 32*2*4*33 because for the last multiplication each student can choose out of 32 minors or no minor = 33 options. The book however says the answer is 32*2*4*32. I am not understanding how they factor in the "no minor" possibility.

Comment: Well i guess you are over thinking it, perhaps one of the minors is no minor at all. You are using the product principle fine.

Comment: Okay, so the question is ambiguous I guess